# i want the questions/start_ask page in the header region of my website

Tags: drupal

I have enabled Answers module and really like the "questions/start_ask" page.
here are my questions

1. i am not able to identify what is this page - a view, custom form or some Panels template -
2. how do i use this in the header REGION as a widget or a custom block?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and [Theme Developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) modules installed? If not, get them. When they're turned on you can click "themer info" in the bottom-left corner of any page, and then hover over anything on the page to find out about the functions, views, and templates that were called to create it.

Comment: yes, thanks thats exactly what i did- got Theme developer module installed and enabled - what an excellent pieces of work this module is!

Comment: Great, glad it helped! Please consider voting this answer up. You can also "accept" the final answer you added to help future readers find it (click the checkmark next to the question).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed - I got the form working in my header by adding a new region in page.tpl and then 
`<?php print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('answers_start_ask_form')); ?>` + some css to position and color things.
you can see it working here [www.onlinedoctors.in](http://www.onlinedoctors.in)